# AMP email - [checked] bound attribute doesn't affect checkbox status

Tags: html, amp-html, amp-email, amp-list

I have an AMP email and I want checkboxes to appear as checked or unchecked depending on a value coming from my server. If the value `{{done}}` is false, I want the box to appear unchecked and if `{{done}}` is true, I want the box checked.

Here is the code for the email:

```
               <amp-list                             
                            template="checklist-item-template"
                            src="MY_SOURCE_URL"
                            layout="responsive"
                            binding="refresh" 
                            width="600"
                            height="56"
                            ><template
                                id="checklist-item-template"
                                type="amp-mustache"
                            >
                                <div class="task-row outline">
                                    <div class="task task-checkbox">
                                        <input
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            id="checkbox-{{id}}"
                                            value="checked"
                                            name="{{id}}"
                                            [checked]="{{done}}"
                                            on="change:checklist-form.submit"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="task task-name">
                                        {{done}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="task small-text task-icons">
                                        {{deadline}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="task task-burger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                            <div overflow class="list-overflow">
                                See more
                            </div>
                        </amp-list>
```

The other dynamic fields populate correctly. My problem is that I can't pass the `done` boolean directly into the `checked` attribute because `false` is rendered as a string, which is truthy and checks the box.

I have found a very similar question for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056558/check-uncheck-radio-input-field-not-updated-properly-on-amp/51129603). This approach is what I originally used and it worked well. However, now my checkboxes are unchecked regardless of the value passed into the `[checked]` attribute.

I suspect that there may be some ongoing development with AMP email as I had [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259530/amp-email-form-causes-error-amp-form-form-submission-failed-error-request-vi/65500935#65500935), which was confirmed by the AMP team to be a bug at their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You are using `[checked]`, which is the syntax for attribute binding and only works if `amp-bind` is imported. You need to add  `<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>`.

  - Maybe AMP should print a warning to the JS console for better developer experience, so consider filing a feature request.
- You are using `binding=refresh` on `amp-list`, which tells the component to only evaluate binding when refreshing the list and *not* during the initial load of the list. To evaluate `[checked]` on initial load, you need `binding=always` or omit the `binding` attribute altogether.

Comment: I had added the script tag but you are absolutely right about the binding attribute. `binding="always"` fixed this! Thanks!